# Laravel 9 Localization got error Missing parameter: id when cast parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

here I want to ask about laravel localization. especially for "Missing parameter: id" error when I want to display data based on parameter id

This is my error:

[image]

My route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}', 'where' => ['language' => 'id|en']], function() {

    Route::controller(LPNewsController::class)->group(function () {
        Route::get('/news/{id}', 'show',)->name('lp-news-show');
    });
});
```

My controller:

```
public function show($lang, $id)
{
    $data = MNews::find($id);
            
    return view('lp_layouts.news.show', compact('data'));
}
```

My button on index view, to cast parameter:

```
<a href="{{ route('lp-news-show', [ app()->getLocale(), $item->id ]) }}"> Link </a>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your href tag to

```
<a href="{{ route('lp-news-show', ['language' => app()->getLocale(), 'id' => $item->id ]) }}"> Link </a>
```

Comment: i already change that href, but keep got same error

Comment: well its time to debug then, try to run php artisan route:list and see if your route is already registered correctly

Comment: here is the result after i run php artisan route:list
GET|HEAD {language}/news/{id} ......lp-news-show LPNewsController@show

Comment: but the return of $data in the show method, returns the appropriate data

Comment: The problem is in my "blade change language", but this makes the syntax neater, thanks